# variance of the product of two samples with awgn

Tags: sampling

problem solved itself, sorry for your inconvenience. I'll try to post better questions next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a paper, which is more general than Gaussian distributions.

> Bohrnstedt, George W., and Arthur S. Goldberger. "On the exact
>   covariance of products of random variables." Journal of the American
>   Statistical Association 64.328 (1969): 1439-1442.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2286081.pdf?casa_token=m1_rSG4hiwIAAAAA:sGjisD6dekanCat5EBGl0yvdn1EJ5LY783fq4VKdxNhd0RA4z4izkcyDJ6yU7MylDke_qD335SWUNu1gJ5opTzXFWIVQWDrjoMvxcFgvMBEgG6r8En0W

Their equation (9)
$$
 V(xy) = E^2(x)V(y) + E^2(y)V(x) + V(x)V(y). \quad (9)
$$
reduces to your result